# IBM Cloud - CF configuration Remote server error

Tags: ibm-cloud

We get the error below when we try to login. We get the same error for another account too. The CLI had to be updated before the login attempt. We could login last week.

```
Installing version '0.14.0'...
Downloading...
 18.18 MiB / 18.18 MiB [==================================================] 100.00% 7s
19058416 bytes downloaded
```

**The error:**

```
PS C:\> ibmcloud login  -o xxxxxxxx -s dev -sso
API endpoint: https://api.w3ibm.bluemix.net

Public IAM token service is available in the dedicated environment.
Login with your public IBMid, or use '--no-iam' to login as a dedicated user only.


Get One Time Code from https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx to proceed.
Open the URL in the default browser? [Y/n]> Y
One Time Code >
Authenticating...
OK

Connected to dedicated user xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

API endpoint:   https://api.w3ibm.bluemix.net
Region:         w3ibm:prod:us-south
Not logged in. Use 'C:\Program Files\IBM\Cloud\bin\ibmcloud.exe login' to log in.
FAILED
Could not set account:
Remote server error. Status code: 400, error code: BXNIM0141E, message: The user 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is not member of the account 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details? What command did you run? Are you able to login from UI  https://console.bluemix.net ? If you are able to login through console, get account id from https://console.bluemix.net/account/billing

Comment: I was trying to login in a internal bluemix. I solved it using ibmcloud login --sso --no-iam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was solved just using 
        ibmcloud login --sso --no-iam

Comment: This did help me get over the error but doesn't seem to have visibility into my org's and spaces when setting a target.

Comment: You should try to use `ibmcloud target --cf` to view and set your orgs and spaces.